# ¿Como acceder al valor de varios inputs sin usar tantos querySelector en JS?

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito acceder al valor de mas de 10 inputs de un Html, pero no quiero declarar tantas variables en mi archivo JS.

En pocas palabras quiciera resumir este codigo:

```js
const $dato1 = document.querySelector('#dato1');
const $dato2 = document.querySelector('#dato2');
const $dato3 = document.querySelector('#dato3');
const $dato4 = document.querySelector('#dato4');
const $dato5 = document.querySelector('#dato5');
const $dato6 = document.querySelector('#dato6');
const $dato7 = document.querySelector('#dato7');
const $dato8 = document.querySelector('#dato8');
```

Comment: Puedes darle la misma clase a todos y usar `querySelectorAll`

Comment: A. Cedano te ha dado una buena solución, pero me pregunto si eso es para rellenar un formulario, y porque luego tienes que acceder a todos y cada uno de ellos.  Si es para pasarlo a una peticion ajax tienes otros métodos que no necesitan recopilar los datos uno a uno previamente, sino de forma conjunta.  Mira que no estes exponiendo un [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY) y si es así agrega a la pregunta algo más de código y lo que realmente pretendes hacer con el.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para alcanzar varios elementos a la vez, puedes usar [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Puedes seleccionar según varios criterios, como clase CSS, tipo de elemento, estado del elemento, etc. Luego, puedes usar esa selección para asignar listeners o lo que sea.

Veamos un ejemplo donde se seleccionan en un formulario sólo los `input` que tenga la clase `form1` y luego se le asigna un listener para escuchar los cambios de esos input.

```js
var allFormOne = document.querySelectorAll('.form1');

allFormOne.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log(`Ha cambiado el input ${e.target.id} \nTu sueldo se multiplicará por: ${e.target.value}`);

  });
});
```

```html
<p>Cambia el valor de algún input y puede que te lleves una sorpresa, o puede que no, depende...</p>
<form>
  <input class="form1" id="dato1" value="1" />
  <input class="form1" id="dato2" value="2" />
  <input class="form1" id="dato3" value="3" />
  <input id="dato4" value="Este no" />

</form>
```

Como ya comentó algún compañero, si es para recoger datos de un formulario, existen otras APIs más específicas, como FormData.