# como enviar dos o mas valores generados de mysql dentro de un while al cambiar un input

Tags: javascript, php

estoy generando una tabla con datos de mysql y en cada fila se ingresa un input de tipo number, lo que hago es que al cambiar el valor del input me mande los values de 2 inputs diferentes pero al hacerlo solo me manda valores del primer recorrido del while. Sé que se deben de hacer ids dinámicas para que los datos no sean los mismo pero no sé implementarlo, les agradecería mucho su ayuda

Aquí es donde genero las tablas

```
<table class="tabla1" id="padre"><tr>
        <th>Imagen</th>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Marca</th>
        <th>Talla</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Disponible</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Quitar</th>
        
    <?php
        include_once("../Consultas/Conexion.php");
        session_start();
        $IdUsuario = $_SESSION['IdUsuario'];

        $Consulta = "SELECT * FROM ventas v JOIN prenda p ON v.IdPrenda=p.IdPrenda JOIN tipprenda tp ON p.IdTipoPrenda=tp.IdTipoPrenda JOIN marca m ON p.IdMarca=m.IdMarca JOIN talla t ON p.IdTalla=t.IdTalla WHERE v.IdUsuario='$IdUsuario' AND Carrito='si'";
        $resp = mysqli_query($cn, $Consulta);
        if ($resp->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resp)) {
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img height='100' width='100' src="<?php echo "../".$fila['RutaImagen']; ?>"/></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['NomPrenda']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['NomMarca']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['NomTalla']; ?></td>   
                <td><?php echo $fila['Color']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['Cantidad']; ?></td>

                <th><input type="number" id="CantNumProducto" name="CantNumProducto" min="0" max="100" class="txtNumber" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $fila['CantidadVenta']; ?>"></th>

                <td><?php echo number_format($fila['Precio'], 2, '.', ','); ?></td>

                <td><div id="getTotal"></div></td>

                <td><button type="submit" value="<?php echo $fila['IdVentas']; ?>" class="btnQuitar" name="btnQuitar2"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $fila['IdVentas']; ?>" class="IdVentas" value="<?php echo $fila['IdVentas']; ?>" hidden>
        <?php 
            }
        } ?>
```

aqui obtengo los valores del input de tipo number y el input de tipo text, cada vez que se cambia el valor de number me manda los valores pero solo del primer recorrido

```
document.getElementById('padre').addEventListener("change", function(event){
if (event.target.classList.contains('txtNumber')) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var parametros = "cantidad=" + event.target.value + "&IdVentas=" +  document.getElementById('IdVentas').value;
    var url = "../Consultas/TotalPrecio.php";

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(parametros);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("getTotal").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: al name del input number agregale "[ ]" esto lo volvera un arreglo de inputs, al enviarse el form, llegará asi mismo, como un arreglo

Comment: lo que tratas de decir es que lo ponga así?  <input name[]="y aqui como lo pongo"> es que soy nuevo en esto y no se varias cosas

Comment: <input type='number' name='CantNumProducto[]' el resto igual como lo tienes>

Comment: te llegará algo parecido a esto [0=>1,1=>22,2=>22] cada key con el value del input

Comment: creo ya lo tengo pero ahora como los mando a php para guardar o actualizar?

Comment: la verdad no puedo si pueden ayudar

Comment: No le veo sentido a tu código. Tú estarías escuchando el evento `change` de las filas de un elemento del tipo `table`, cuando una tabla no es algo que cambie tan fácilmente. Tampoco se entiende lo que quieres hacer, pero, supongo que tienes una tabla y en cada fila un botón para eliminar esa fila ¿?  Si es así, lo que debes escuchar es el evento `click` de cada uno de esos botones, para que se borre la fila sobre la que se presionó o algo así. Si explicas con claridad el problema, olvidando la solución que estás intentando, la cual puede ser equivocada de entrada, podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: estoy haciendo un tipo carrito de compras asi que cada vez que el valor del input number cambie pues ese valor y el id me lo tiene que mandar a otro php para hacer las consultas y operaciones de multiplicar la cantidad*precio del producto y me lo muestre en cada fila de los datos correspondidos a dicho cambio del number

Comment: *... asi que cada vez que el valor del input number cambie pues ese valor y el id me lo tiene que mandar a otro php...* Ahí tienes la respuesta. El evento que tienes que escuchar es el `onchange` de los `input` que refieres, pero en el código se ve que intentas escuchar los cambios de una tabla: `document.getElementById('padre').addEventListener("change", function(event){` Así no funcionará. Tú puedes agrupar los `input` por una clase, por tipo de elemento, etc y luego asignar el listener a cada elemento de ese grupo. Por otra parte, no debes asignar nunca ids repetidos a los elementos.

Comment: [Aquí te dejo un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/509746/29967) donde se escuchan los cambios de todos los `input` que tienen asignada la clase `form1`. Es algo así lo que necesitas para tu caso.